# WS2812B NeoPixels no longer working after cutting the strip and adding an extension

Tags: neopixel, ws2812

I am trying to use WS2812B LEDs with an Arduino.
I have 24 LEDs connected to pin 6.

When I first received the strip I connected it to 12V and data.
Using the cyclone example in the FastLED library worked.

But then I cut them and added extension wires.
I have 3 LEDs on single strip; so it is 8 strips of 3 LEDs.
The extension is about 30cm long.
Now when I power them, they just glow bright white.

So, I thought the extension wire was the problem.
I removed extension and connected them as they came.
But still, they are turning on bright white.

I connected the Arduino out to DIN.

Comment: I thought WS2812B LEDs took 5V, and not 12. If I'm right, you may have fried something. Also, check to see if you reconnected them the right way around; there are usually arrows/labels on the strip for guidance. You could try if you can get one strip of three LEDs to work with the right voltage, and take it from there.

Comment: WS2812Bs work at 5V. You may have fried them at 12V. Also, take care to connect the Dout of the first strip to the Din of the second, and so on.

Comment: Mate, I think you may fried the led strip, as the strip work on 5V (even with 3.3V iirc)... Anyways, just try to cut the first led and hook up your uC (arduino or any other) to the (back in time) 2nd led (now your first led of the strip)

Comment: Are these actually WS2812B or one of the other WS281x series parts?  A link to the exact thing you bought may help.